# Split CSV based on column Value with no formatting

Tags: csv, powershell

I have found many questions and answers for this however it seems I cannot find one that works for me. I need to split a CSV based on a column value. Here is an example of my sheet:

```
<option value="">Choose Year</option>   ParentID
<option value="Civic1990">1990</option> Civic
<option value="CRX1990">1990</option>   CRX
<option value="Prelude1990">1990</option>   Prelude
<option value="Accord1990">1990</option>    Accord
<option value="Prelude1991">1991</option>   Prelude
<option value="Civic1991">1991</option> Civic
<option value="CRX1991">1991</option>   CRX
<option value="Accord1991">1991</option>    Accord
<option value="Prelude1992">1992</option>   Prelude
<option value="Civic1992">1992</option> Civic
<option value="Accord1992">1992</option>    Accord
<option value="Prelude1993">1993</option>   Prelude
<option value="Civic1993">1993</option> Civic
<option value="CivicdelSol1993">1993</option>   CivicdelSol
<option value="Accord1993">1993</option>    Accord
<option value="Passport1994">1994</option>  Passport
<option value="Accord1994">1994</option>    Accord
<option value="Prelude1994">1994</option>   Prelude
<option value="Civic1994">1994</option> Civic
<option value="CivicdelSol1994">1994</option>   CivicdelSol
<option value="Passport1995">1995</option>  Passport
<option value="Accord1995">1995</option>    Accord
<option value="Odyssey1995">1995</option>   Odyssey
<option value="Prelude1995">1995</option>   Prelude
<option value="Civic1995">1995</option> Civic
<option value="CivicdelSol1995">1995</option>   CivicdelSol
<option value="Passport1996">1996</option>  Passport
<option value="Accord1996">1996</option>    Accord
<option value="Odyssey1996">1996</option>   Odyssey
<option value="Prelude1996">1996</option>   Prelude
<option value="Civic1996">1996</option> Civic
```

I need to split based on the "ParentID" column and include ONLY the option values. I am currently using PowerShell however even when excluding data type there is still formatting in the output txt files that the server is reading when I place the txt files.

These option values are used for a dropdown so I need that formatting to be gone.

Is there a way to do this in python or another program that will split without the formatting so the website can read the txt files?

Here is my current PowerShell script:

```
$fullpath = "C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\YHP Revamp\New Cache 02-3\SubGroup\SubGroup.csv"

$path = Split-Path $fullpath -parent
$data = Import-CSV -Delimiter "," -Path $fullpath -Header "<option value="">Choose SubGroup</option>",ParentID

foreach ($group in $data | Group ParentID) {
    $data | Where-Object {$_.ParentID -eq $group.name} | 
        select * -ExcludeProperty ParentID |
        ConvertTo-Csv|   
        foreach {$_.Replace('#TYPE Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject','')} |
        foreach {$_.Replace('"<','<')} |
        foreach {$_.Replace('>"','>')} |
        foreach {$_.Replace('"">','">')} |
        foreach {$_.Replace('=""','="')} |
        foreach {$_.Replace('=">','="">')} |
        Out-File "$path\$($group.name).txt"
}
```

Comment: How was this "csv" generated? This looks like partial XML. I would be more looking at controlling how this was created. This is not a CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your input file is actually a tab-separated text file I'd process it like this:

```
Import-Csv $fullpath -Delimiter "`t" -Header Year, ParentID |
  Select-Object -Skip 1 |
  ForEach-Object {
    $parent = $_.ParentID
    $_.Year -replace '.*?"(.*?)".*', '$1' | Out-File "$path\$parent.txt" -Append
  }
```

The combination of `-Header Year, ParentID` and `Select-Object -Skip 1` is to replace the actual header of the first column with something a little more sensible.